# Blue screen over VGA monitor connected to Pi

Tags: pi-4, hdmi, display, screen, kali

I recently bought new raspberry pi 4 2GB and micro hdmi to vga converter. Once i try to connect pi to monitor using converter, os boots perfectly, but over whole monitor screen is light blue color which is really annoying (there is blue color over white, green, etc). I am using Kali ARM on Pi (Debian).
I configured everything on SD card in config.txt file, but i still have this problem. Does anybody know what this could be?

Images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToBjA.jpg,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0AJ1.jpg

Comment: What's the adapter you've bought? Is it faulty because the red channel is missing? Do you get the same if you run plain RaspiOS?

Answer (score -1):

If you have messed with all of the settings. and it still doesn't work, try unplugging and replugging the VGA cable. Try another cable. If the same problem is still there, try replacing the adapter.